# Hide Inno Setup wizard small image

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to hide/remove/not show the small wizard image in top right corner:

[image]

I know there are `WizardSmallImageFile` and `WizardSmallBitmapImage` directives, but I can only set to a specific file, I can't set to *none* or something similar to tell compiler to not show any image there, at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide the `WizardSmallBitmapImage` control:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Visible := False;
end;
```

[image]